# Averaging multiple values in a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration, average

I have a list of tests carried out on a subject, held in a dataframe. There are multiple tests, all of which have been repeated multiple times, at different dates.

I wish to generate an average value for each test using python. I can generate the test name and value using the `iterrows()` function, but then I get stuck.

Below I have included an example of the table structure, there are actually about 30 tests and 200+ rows for this dataset.

This is a small subset of a larger database(1000000+ rows), which the code would be extended to, so I do not want to just bruteforce the result.
Many thanks!

---

```
| Test   | Value  | Date
#--------#--------#--------      
| Test A | 31     | Date1
| Test B | 14     | Date2
| Test A | 25     | Date3
| Test A | 26     | Date1
| Test B | 8      | Date1
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of this problem in the Split-Apply-Combine pattern. In this case, you want to group all the Tests together (split data set by Test & also combine the resulting dataset) & calculate the average of all the Values (apply the mean function on the Values)

This is a good post explaining the grouping and aggregation capabilities of pandas: http://pbpython.com/pandas-grouper-agg.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Test': ['Test A', 'Test B', 'Test A', 'Test A', 'Test B'],
    'Value': [31, 14, 25, 26, 8],
    'Date': ['Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3', 'Date1', 'Date2']}
)
df.Value.groupby(df.Test).agg(np.mean)
```